# Using vim commands in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim

I am very hesitant to ask this question, at the risk of being downvoted & flamed, but I searched & searched, & the most recent thread I can find is from almost 2 yrs ago, so I figure the answer might be different now as technologies have progressed...

That said, the question is the same as it was 2 yrs ago when someone else asked it: I'm a C/C++ developer trying to migrate from vim to Eclipse (in Linux) but really miss the vim commands! It looks like the best choices are Vimplugin, Vrapper, Eclim, Viplugin.

Can anyone share their experiences using these (pros/cons, great features/bad features)? Then perhaps after a couple of people have shared their experiences, anyone who agrees can upvote to demonstrate agreement.

(I realize these types of questions are often frowned upon by experienced users, but they can be immensely helpful to us newbies, so it is much appreciated :-)

thanks!

Comment: Editor preference is not helpful for anyone else besides the one doing the talking. Voting for close.

Comment: I tried all of those options before taking my decision. I think you can do the same.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522896/using-vim-commands-in-eclipse